# Git -- QuickEdit on Command Line?

Tags: windows, git, contextmenu

There are two really useful features for Git that I am trying to combine on windows:

1) QuickEdit Mode, which allows you to paste into the command prompt (this is a windows variable which is set on the shortcut you use to launch). It is set as shown here:

[image: photo of setting QuickEdit]

2) Launching Git from the Context Menu, which allows you to jump straight to a directory, without having to manually browse to it from the Bash (i.e. if you right-click on a folder, then select Git Bash, your Git Bash will open already browsed to that folder). That looks like this:

[image: Git Bash Context Menu Prompt]

BUT, because QuickEdit Mode is a Windows variable (I think), and in any case isn't turned on by default, when you launch Git Bash from the context menu, you lose the ability to paste into the Git Bash... which makes, among other things, cloning or setting up remotes more annoying than it has to be.

Any ideas on how you can set QuickEdit Mode to be turned on when launching Git from the right-click context menu in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

GUI

Command Prompt Window Menu
<kbd>Defaults</kbd>
<kbd>Options</kbd>
<kbd>QuickEdit Mode</kbd>

Reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console]
"QuickEdit"=dword:1
```

Command Prompt

```
REG ADD HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

PowerShell

```
sp -t d HKCU:\Console QuickEdit 1
```

Cygwin

```
regtool set /user/Console/QuickEdit 1
```